# Jquery Ajax Authentication methods running randomly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm working on a simple authentification methods throught Springs and Jquery.
Also I'm not familiar with Jquery I have a question.

Do not blame about security this is just a way for me to learn Ajax.
The issue is that sometime the code decide to run, sometime not.
What I can do to make sure that the Ajax methods runs automaticly.

Also I call the function on a button like this : onClick="Checklogin();"

```
  function checkLogin() {    
   $.ajax({
      type: 'get',
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/rest/api/utilisateurs/'+malo,
      contentType: "application/json",
      data: { id: '', nom:'',prenom:'',mdp:'' },
      success: function (d) { 
            var idx =document.getElementById("ido").value;
            var malo = idx;
            var mdi =document.getElementById("mdp").value;
            var mdp = mdi;
          
          var rico = d.id;
          var roco = d.mdp;
          alert(rico);
          alert(roco);

           if((idx == rico) && (mdp == roco)) {
               alert("Bienvenue " +d.nom+" "+ d.prenom);
               window.location.href="./listecourse.html";
              

            }else {
               alert("Identifiants/Mdp Inccorect");
               window.location.href="./index.html";
                } 
           
           window.location.href="./listecourse.html";
           }

      });
  
    }
```

Thanks in advance for your advices, have a. nice day.

HTML Code

```
</script>
                <form id="loginForm" class="login100-form validate-form p-b-33 p-t-5">

                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Enter username">
                        <input class="input100" placeholder="Enter your id" name="ido" id="ido" required>
                        <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="&#xe82a;"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Enter password">
                        <input class="input100" type="password" placeholder="Enter your Password" name ="mdp" id="mdp" required>
                        <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="&#xe80f;"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="container-login100-form-btn m-t-32">
                        <button class="login100-form-btn" onclick="checkLogin()">
                            Se connecter
                        </button>
                    </div>

                </form>
```

Comment: could you put some of your html code

Comment: @rahul that's done

Comment: are you getting the response from the ajax call correctly

Comment: Yes but sometime it appears that the code won't run